# Android - Fragments, using reference to call instance methods

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have specific fragments which will perform actions in a background thread (or will start activities for result) and I would like to set a callback (from the hosting activity), to get some data from the fragment after such actions, for instance:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
TakePhotoFragment takePhotoFragment = (TakePhotoFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frTakePhoto);
takePhotoFragment.setListener(new TakePhotoFragment.OnNewBitmapListener() {
  @Override
  public void onNewBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // do things in the activity
  }
});
```

I have read that it is safer to feed arguments into the fragment using `Bundle`s, but there are several cases which I would like to pass object references rather than simple `String` data using Bundles. Is there any problem in getting a reference using a `FragmentManager` and calling methods on it? If yes, which are the workarounds?

Comment: if your fragment is not yet created use bundle, otherwise use instance one

Comment: it is safer to pass bundle becoz when android recreate your fragment your pass data in bundle is not lost

Comment: @ColdFire But, if the fragment is already defined in the xml layout, and I get a reference, will it still be problematic? If yes, what can I do?

Comment: if in xml get it directly and no problems, also see my answer

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your fragment is not yet created use bundle, otherwise use instance one.

It is safer to pass bundle becoz when android recreate your fragment your pass data in bundle is not lost.

If you use the instance one to pass data you have to save and restore that data yourself

Note: you can pass complex object through bundle by making them parcelable or serializable.
Also passing big data in bundle is not recommended

If your fragment is defined in xml you can get the instance by `findFragmentById()` of `fragmentManager` class

Comment: Are you sure we can use `View findViewById(int id)` and then cast to a specific `Fragment`? How would be this part, using `findViewById` instead of `fm.findFragmentById`? : `TakePhotoFragment takePhotoFragment = (TakePhotoFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frTakePhoto);`

Comment: @FtheBuilder yes i am sure you can , but only if you define it in xml

Comment: and yes it will be like a normal findViewbyID  and cast to the respective fragment

Comment: maybe indirectly so, because a `View` cannot be explicitly casted to a `Fragment`... Can you show how would you do that?

Comment: oops you are right ,i messed up the method name , you cant by findviewbyID since it cant be casted , edited answer to notify about the same, thanks for catching that

Comment: fm.findFragmentById(‌​R.id.frTakePhoto) is the right way for xml fragment @FtheBuilder